How do I scan linear barcodes in landscape using Swift's AVCaptureSession
In Swift, using AVCaptureSession, I used to be able to scan linear barcodes (I.e. Code 39, Coe 128) in my iOS app in both Portrait and Landscape mode. Apple recently fixed a bug with QR codes in version 17.4.1. Now it seems, since the update, I am no longer able to scan any linear barcodes in landscape mode.  Is anybody else experiencing this issue? Or can anyone help me understand what I might be doing wrong? Here is the code I am currently running. QR codes seem to work fine regardless of camera orientation, but linear codes only seem to work in portrait and portrait upside down; neither landscape. Is this by design in Apple's new update perhaps?
    func preparePreviewLayer() {
        // Clear all previously created scanner graphics
        self.layer.sublayers?.removeAll()
        
        // Create new session for camera
        captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
        
        guard let videoCaptureDevice = AVCaptureDevice.default(for: .video) else {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.delegate?.initFailed(error: "Could not find video device.")
            }
            
            return
        }
        
        let videoInput: AVCaptureDeviceInput

        do {
            videoInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: videoCaptureDevice)
        } catch {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.delegate?.initFailed(error: "Could not find video device.")
            }
            
            return
        }

        if captureSession.canAddInput(videoInput) {
            captureSession.addInput(videoInput)
        } else {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.delegate?.initFailed(error: "Video capture failed.")
            }
            
            return
        }

        let metadataOutput = AVCaptureMetadataOutput()
        
        if captureSession.canAddOutput(metadataOutput) {
            captureSession.addOutput(metadataOutput)
            
            metadataOutput.setMetadataObjectsDelegate(self, queue: DispatchQueue.main)
            metadataOutput.rectOfInterest = scanPreviewLayer.metadataOutputRectConverted(fromLayerRect: layer.bounds)
            
            metadataOutput.metadataObjectTypes = [.code128, .code39]
            
            // Successfully scans QR codes in Portrait and Landscape
            //metadataOutput.metadataObjectTypes = [.qr]
            
            // Only scans 128 codes in Portrait or Portrait Upside Down                //metadataOutput.metadataObjectTypes = [.code128]
            
            // Successfully scans QR codes in Portrait and Landscape, and only scans 128 codes in Portrait or Portrait Upside Down
            //metadataOutput.metadataObjectTypes = [.qr, .code128]
            
        } else {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.delegate?.scanFailed(error: "This device does not support barcode scanning.")
            }
            
            return
        }
        
        scanPreviewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
        scanPreviewLayer.frame = self.layer.bounds
        scanPreviewLayer.videoGravity = .resizeAspectFill
        
        self.layer.addSublayer(scanPreviewLayer)
        
        refreshCameraOrientation()
    }
    
    func refreshCameraOrientation() {
        if captureSession != nil {
            if let connection =  self.scanPreviewLayer?.connection  {
                let currentDevice: UIDevice = UIDevice.current
                let orientation: UIDeviceOrientation = currentDevice.orientation
                let previewLayerConnection : AVCaptureConnection = connection
                
                if previewLayerConnection.isVideoOrientationSupported {
                    switch (orientation) {
                        case .portrait:
                            previewLayerConnection.videoOrientation = .portrait
                        case .landscapeRight:
                            previewLayerConnection.videoOrientation = .landscapeLeft
                        case .landscapeLeft:
                            previewLayerConnection.videoOrientation = .landscapeRight
                        case .portraitUpsideDown:
                            previewLayerConnection.videoOrientation = .portraitUpsideDown
                        default:
                            previewLayerConnection.videoOrientation = .portrait
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

